# Unable to read formgroup value in a validator

Tags: angular

I have a Angular reactive form here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-duplicate-validation-xmctog?file=src/app/app.component.ts

In the isNameDuplicate method when i try to accesses the form value I am getting an error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
>       at AppComponent.isNameDuplicate (app.component.ts:39)

And the line that is raising the error is in the isNameDuplicate Validator.

```
isNameDuplicate(c:AbstractControl)  
  {
    let value = c.value;
    console.log(value);
    const hasDuplicate:boolean = false;
    const userNames = this.form
    console.log(userNames);
    // const names = userNames.map(item=> item.username.trim());
    // const hasDuplicate = names.some(
    // (name, index) => names.indexOf(name, index + 1) != -1
  //);
    return null;
  }
```

This line const userNames = this.form raises the error why i can't accesses the form using this.form ?

How do i go about over coming this error ?

Comment: You can get access to `this` in the validation code by binding `this`. `validators:[this.isNameDuplicate.bind(this)]` [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-duplicate-validation-e6ds1x?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks Nathan yes that seems to do the trick the javascript aha moment with this isn't it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export a function then reference it.
Per the [examples](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)

```
/** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

This example muddies the waters with double negatives..

forbidden - because it can't match Regex.

(regex test would return true for a match)

See my example later for a simpler answer.

...

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
    ]),
    'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo),
    'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
  });
```

...

```
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>
```

...

If it helps, here's one I did for a simple min control (**utils.ts**)

```
export function min(min: Number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      const input = control.value,
      isValid = input < min;
      if(isValid) 
          return { 'minValue': {min} }
      else 
          return null;
    };
}
```

Used here in an Ionic App 3 . It has slightly difference lifecycle hooks to Angular 4, but for what you want it suffices.

```
import { FormBuilder, 
         FormControl,
         FormGroup, 
         Validators }       from '@angular/forms'; 
import { min }              from '../../util/util';
export class MachinesPage {
  constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder
  ) {
     this.createPageForm();
  }

  private createPageForm():void {
    console.log('MachinesPage: createPageForm()');
    this.pnFG = this.fb.group({
      pageNumberInput: [this.spp.page,
                        Validators.compose([
                            Validators.required,
                            min(1)
                        ])
                      ]
    });
  }
...
}
```

Useful APi links:

- https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn
- https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors

Comment: Interesting i thought in my stack biltz example i am in the same file as the component so exporting does not make sense to me.

Comment: The validator has to return a ValidatorFn. You are right in as much as you don't need to export it. https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors

Comment: Who gave this a -1? It's valid

Comment: Not me i think its stupid to award a negative mark without explaining why

Comment: The only thing I can think of is AJT_82 did it. The crazy thing is the question that it is marked as a duplicate for is tagged as both angularjs and angular - so that would throw anyone for starters! Also IIRC if you are using template driven forms you can use directives for custom validators too.

Comment: I am using reactive forms and come to think of it your solution is elegant as it does not use the this mumbo jumbo :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context to the validator:

```
addCreds() {
  const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
  creds.push(this.fb.group({
    username: ['', {
      validators: [this.isNameDuplicate(this)],
      updateOn: 'blur'
    }],
    password: '',
  }));
}


isNameDuplicate(context): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    if (true) {
      console.log(context.form);
      return { 'valid': true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```